# complex xml to csv using python

Tags: python, xml, csv

```
<app>
<doc>
<field name="id">013</field>
<field name="groupid">013</field>
<field name="img_url">8b4</field>
<field name="filetype">HTML</field>
<field name="url">https://calgaryherald.com/pmn/business-pmn/sally-rumbles-toward-u-s-/</field>
<field name="topic">accurate</field>
<field name="topic">additional</field>
<field name="topic">agriculture</field>
<field name="topic">area</field>
<field name="topic">biggest</field>
</doc>
<doc>
<field name="id">0131</field>
<field name="groupid">013</field>
<field name="img_url">8b</field>
<field name="filetype">HTML</field>
<field name="url">https://calgaryherald.com/pmn/business-pmn/sally-rumbles-toward</field>
<field name="topic">accurate</field>
<field name="topic">additional</field>
<field name="topic">agriculture</field>
<field name="topic">area</field>
<field name="topic">biggest1</field>
<field name="topic">biggest2</field>
<field name="topic">biggest3</field>
</doc>
</app>
```

I have a xml similar to this i need to convert it to a csv in python. Does anyone know how to do it and also the field name topic differs for different doc and the csv headers should be similar to the field name and for topics it should be in a single cell with comma separated.

Expected Output
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ff0Cy.png)

Comment: Are the field names known in advance? how would you like to store multiple topics in the csv. I assume they should be some sort of list in a single "topics" column. Would they be comma separated, kinda like a csv embedded in the csv cell?

Comment: @tdelaney yes the field names are know in advance. and topics should be comma separated in a single cell

Comment: By "topics should be comma separated" do you mean that each row will have a variable number of columns depending on # of topics, or that there should be a single topics column where its internal commas are escaped?

Comment: @tdelaney topics should be comma separated and should be in single column

Comment: how should the csv look like? (based on the xml in the post). Add this info to the post please.

Comment: @mzjn - usually I'd agree, but in this case I think OP doesn't know which tool in the toolkit to grab. There are many ways to solve this problem which makes it kinda off topic for stackoverflow, but since iterparsers aren't common knowledge, I took a stab at it anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an XML parser that emits element data as it parses to build the csv. On every end tag, you could either add a value to the row or write the row itself. One advantage of iterparse is that you don't need to load the entire document into memory before processing.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import io
import csv

field_names = ["id", "groupid", "img_url", "filetype", "url", "topic"]
field_names_set = set(field_names)

with open("test.csv", "w", newline="") as out_file:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(out_file, field_names)
    writer.writeheader()
    row = {}
    topic = []
    for event, elem in ET.iterparse("test.xml"): # iterate tag end events
        if elem.tag == "doc":
            # doc elem end, write row to csv and setup for next
            row["topic"] = ",".join(topic)
            writer.writerow(row)
            row = {}
            topic = []            
        elif elem.tag == "field":
            # field elem end, add to current row
            if elem.attrib["name"] == "topic":
                topic.append(elem.text)
            else:
                row[elem.attrib["name"]] = elem.text
```

Answer (score 0):

The below creates a csv like output. Is that what you are looking for?
Note that you cant tell which field is a 'topic' and which field is non 'topic'

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
xml = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<app>
   <doc>
      <field name="id">013</field>
      <field name="groupid">013</field>
      <field name="img_url">8b4</field>
      <field name="filetype">HTML</field>
      <field name="url">https://calgaryherald.com/pmn/business-pmn/sally-rumbles-toward-u-s-/</field>
      <field name="topic">accurate</field>
      <field name="topic">additional</field>
      <field name="topic">agriculture</field>
      <field name="topic">area</field>
      <field name="topic">biggest</field>
   </doc>
   <doc>
      <field name="id">0131</field>
      <field name="groupid">013</field>
      <field name="img_url">8b</field>
      <field name="filetype">HTML</field>
      <field name="url">https://calgaryherald.com/pmn/business-pmn/sally-rumbles-toward</field>
      <field name="topic">accurate</field>
      <field name="topic">additional</field>
      <field name="topic">agriculture</field>
      <field name="topic">area</field>
      <field name="topic">biggest1</field>
      <field name="topic">biggest2</field>
      <field name="topic">biggest3</field>
   </doc>
</app>'''
root = ET.fromstring(xml)
first_time = True
headers = set()
for doc in root.findall('.//doc'):
    data = []
    for field in doc.findall('field'):
        if first_time:
            headers.add(field.attrib['name'])
        data.append((field.attrib['name'], field.text))
    if first_time:
        print(','.join(sorted(list(headers))))
        first_time = False
    print(','.join(y[1] for y in sorted(data, key=lambda x: x[0])))
```

output

```
filetype,groupid,id,img_url,topic,url
HTML,013,013,8b4,accurate,additional,agriculture,area,biggest,https://calgaryherald.com/pmn/business-pmn/sally-rumbles-toward-u-s-/
HTML,013,0131,8b,accurate,additional,agriculture,area,biggest1,biggest2,biggest3,https://calgaryherald.com/pmn/business-pmn/sally-rumbles-toward
```

Comment: thanks you so much, i got an idea how to format it .

Comment: @joemarshal Do you want to share with the world the desired output?

Comment: i have added the output picture in the post